# Compilation issue with JDBC under Apache Ant

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ant, oracle11g

I am using the following specification for JDBC compilations using Ant.

```
<sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.184.133.133:1521:SUPP"
        userid="${UsernameB}"
        password="${PasswordB}"
        onerror="continue"
        delimitertype="row"
        delimiter="/"
        keepformat="yes">
```

The delimiter here is slash (/). If there are spaces after the slash the compilation is not happening properly. Is there any way I can avoid this situation?

Comment: What is the relevance of the Perl tag here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that if you have a space after the slashes separating the SQL statements it won't compile?

I suggest you add

```
strictDelimiterMatching="false"
```

which force recognition of the delimiter to be case-insensitive (which is irrelevant here) and to ignore surrounding whitespace.

Comment: sql doesn't support the "strictDelimiterMatching" attribute. I am getting the above error for this

Comment: Ant 1.7 is six years old! The `strictDelimiterMatching` attribute has been available since Ant 1.8.0 in February 2010. I think you have no option but to either fix your SQL code or update your Ant installation.